# Javascript string array ordering (based on value order)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently using a typewriter effect from [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Milleus/pen/YzKOjoO) and would like to order strings in the order in which they are listed (not random).

```
function getRandomPun() {
  const puns = [
    "String one",
    "String two",
    "String three"
  ];
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * puns.length);

  return puns[index];
}

startType(getRandomPun(), 0);
```

I have tried replacing the index with `Math.floor(Math.round(puns.length)` but it has no effect.

```
function getThePun() {
  const puns = [
    "String one",
    "String two",
    "String three"
  ];
  const index = Math.floor(Math.round(puns.length);

  return puns[index];
}

startType(getThePun(), 0);
```

I also tried the following but only the first string it outputted:

```
function getThePun() {
  const puns = [
    "String one",
    "String two",
    "String three"
  ];
  return puns[0];
}

startType(getThePun(), 0);
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"to order strings by length **or the order in which they are listed**"_ - This doesn't make sense. And how does randomness help with that? o.O -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andreas - I am trying to remove the random order, initially by trying to get the rounded number of the string's length (although this would be round anyway).

Comment: 3 elements, pick one, don't want it random... are you looking for `return puns[0];`?

Comment: Hi tevemadar, thanks for your reply!

I had tried:

```
function getThePun() {
  const puns = [
    "building websites",
    "Shopify builds",
    "Wordpress development"
  ];
  return puns[0];
}

startType(getThePun(), 0);
```

But only the first string was outputted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the usecase is here, but here is how to sort

```js
const puns = [
  "String shortest",
  "String - the longest",
  "String three long"
];

function getRandomPun(len) {
  if (len) puns.sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length)
  console.log(puns)
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * puns.length);

  return puns[index];
}

console.log(getRandomPun());
console.log(getRandomPun(true));
```